# How to make a custom sculpting brush using the bake function

Tags: baking, sculpting

Made two objects a plane and a pyramid then bake using the displacement mode with select to active.
[image]

The output from the bake is grey for the plane and flat white for the pyramid. When the image texture is used as a sculpt brush it doesn't create the same pyramid shape that was used for the bake. Don't know what I have done wrong could I have some help please.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to do? Are you trying to bake the pyramid shape into a texture?

Comment: I'm trying to make a custom sculpt brush that puts a pyramid shape onto a mesh when in sculpt mode. But the sculpt brush that i made and loaded into blender using texture that you can see in the lower window just sculpts a square shape with a bit of a bump.

Comment: Can you post how your texture looks?

Comment: added image to the original question

Comment: Try enabling normalized in the bake settings. You could place a camera above the cone and use the z-depth from the render for the brush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think you can have such a deep point on a displacement texture. That's why it just bakes a white square. Your brush is essentially just a square brush.

I quickly made an example of how the texture should actually look like. It's not precise but it's to give you an idea.

[image]

Comment: Basically did the same as your screen shot but added a invert node [link]http://imgur.com/a/kaB8C which gave a better result but still isn't exactly what I was trying to achieve [link]http://imgur.com/a/VPVog Do you think I'm attaching the texture to the wrong sculpt brush should I apply it to another sculpt brush that blender has like the clay brush?

Comment: Ok just needed to change the curve to this. http://imgur.com/a/uZ1vg fixed :) thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Give it a check if you believe it answered you correctly so others can know. ;)